# AngularJS watch all inputs for focus

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope

I want to watch for a focus event on all `input` in the app.

Something like this:

```
$scope.$watch('input',function(e){
  if(e.focus){
    // do stuff
  }
});
```

Any ideas how this can be done?

Comment: are you setting watch for input element or an scope variable ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't watch for an event, you listen to it. Also, messing with DOM is a task for a directive. Therefore, this answer uses the directive approach. You can emit an event or do all the "stuff" internally.

```js
angular.module('app', [])
  .directive('input', function() {
    return {
      restrict: 'E',
      link: Link
    };

    function Link(scope, elem, attrs) {
      elem.on('focus', function() {
        // do stuff
        console.log(elem[0].name + ' has been focused!');
      });
    }
  });
```

```html
<div ng-app="app">
  <label for="input1">input1</label>
  <input name="input1" type="text">
  <label for="input2">input2</label>
  <input name="input2" type="text">
</div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Perfect! This is exactly what I was looking for.